# Why doesn't the new shower hose have the same protruding screw as the old one?

Tags: shower, hose

I was just about to change my old shower hose, and I noticed that the new one doesn't fit, because it doesn't have a similar screw as the old one, as you can see in the following picture. The old one is on the left, the new one on the right. Also, on the producer's website, it says "This shower hose is compatible with most shower heads, with the flexible hose and stainless steel body."

[image]

Comment: That one on the left looks unusual. Are you sure you can't get a grip on the protruding piece and unscrew it from the old hose so you can use it on the new one?

Comment: looks sort of like a quick connect(?). Could there be some sort of adapter where it attached? What did you do to remove it?

Comment: That's how I unscrewed it. It could be an adapter, true, but I couldn't budge it. I'll try a bit more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is an adapter stuck in your old shower hose. You can try to remove it (needle nose pliers and a wrench might work here) or look for a similar adapter at your local hardware store.